# Lean Mergesort using increasing well founded relation

Tags: algorithm, mergesort, lean

I am trying to create the mergesort definition in Lean and have created the following code:

```
def mergesort (a: ℕ): list ℕ → list ℕ     
    | [] := []    
    | [a] := [a]  
    | (x::xs) :=  merge (mergesort (fhalf xs)) (mergesort (sndhalf xs))
```

With the merge definition

```
def merge : list ℕ → list ℕ → list ℕ    
    | xs [] := xs    
    | [] ys := ys
    | (x :: xs) (y :: ys) := if x < y then x :: (merge xs ( y :: ys)) 
                                      else y :: (merge (x :: xs) ys)
```

And fhalf / sndhalf definitions:

```
 def fhalf {α: Type} (xs: list α): list α := 
    list.take (list.length xs/2) xs

def sndhalf {α: Type} (xs: list α): list α :=
    list.drop (list.length xs/2) xs
```

However, I get the following error message:

> failed to prove recursive application is decreasing, well founded
>   relation
>
> ```
> @has_well_founded.r (list ℕ)
> (@has_well_founded_of_has_sizeof (list ℕ) (@list.has_sizeof ℕ nat.has_sizeof))
> ```
>
> Possible solutions:
>
> - Use `using_well_founded` keyword in the end of your definition to specify tactics for synthesizing well founded relations and decreasing proofs.
> - The default decreasing tactic uses the 'assumption' tactic, thus hints (aka local proofs) can be provided using 'have'-expressions. The nested exception contains the failure state for the decreasing tactic.

Can anyone help me to prove that the mergesort is decreasing?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "increasing definition"?

Comment: BTW, your definition of `mergesort` doesn't look quite right: it looks as though you're throwing away the `x` at the head of the list. And do you have your definitions of `fhalf` and `sndhalf` available?

Comment: I have edited my question. I meant to prove that the mergesort is indeed decreasing properly. The problem occurs when I use the list.take and list.drop functions within the definition.

Comment: Have you tried [`list.partition`](https://github.com/leanprover/lean/blob/30d883efef422facab3bf351d9fcff90c943298f/library/init/data/list/basic.lean#L135-L137)? It translates more naturally to the notion of a deterministic base case (aka decreasing ...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, notice that there are multiple problems with your definition of `mergesort`. One, the parameter `a` is unnecessary and never used. (The `a` that you match in the second line is fresh.) Two, in the `x::xs` case, you forget about `x` entirely. To see what your function is actually doing, you can add the keyword `meta`, as in `meta def mergesort`. This disables termination checking, so then you can `#eval mergesort 2 [1, 3, 2]` and see that you do not get what you want. I'll continue to answer this as you've written it.

There is a default well-founded relation, and the default method for proving it is to look for proofs in the local context. You can see what proofs Lean is expecting by looking at the error messages in your definition: it wants proofs of `list.sizeof (fhalf xs) < x + (1 + list.sizeof xs)` and `list.sizeof (sndhalf xs) < x + (1 + list.sizeof xs)`. So by adding lines

```
def mergesort (a : ℕ): list ℕ → list ℕ     
| [] := []    
| [a] := [a]  
| (x::xs) := 
  have list.sizeof (fhalf xs) < x + (1 + list.sizeof xs), from sorry,
  have list.sizeof (sndhalf xs) < x + (1 + list.sizeof xs), from sorry,
  merge (mergesort (fhalf xs)) (mergesort (sndhalf xs))
```

this strategy will succeed. You need to fill in those `sorry`s.

Using the `linarith` tactic available in `mathlib` (via `import tactic.linarith`) you can skip some arithmetic:

```
def mergesort (a : ℕ): list ℕ → list ℕ     
| [] := []    
| [a] := [a]  
| (x::xs) := 
  have list.sizeof (fhalf xs) ≤ list.sizeof xs, from sorry,
  have list.sizeof (sndhalf xs) ≤ list.sizeof xs, from sorry,
  have list.sizeof (fhalf xs) < x + (1 + list.sizeof xs), by linarith,
  have list.sizeof (sndhalf xs) < x + (1 + list.sizeof xs), by linarith,
  merge (mergesort (fhalf xs)) (mergesort (sndhalf xs))
```

So replace those `sorry`s with proofs, and you're good to go. You probably want to prove something like

```
lemma sizeof_take_le {α} [h : has_sizeof α] : ∀ n (xs : list α), 
  list.sizeof (list.take n xs) ≤ list.sizeof xs
```

The details will change a little when you correct your definition of `mergesort`.

An alternative approach is to change the well founded relation and decision tactic, as is done in the `mathlib` definition: https://github.com/leanprover/mathlib/blob/master/data/list/sort.lean#L174
Unfortunately, the interface for doing this is rather low-level and I don't know if or where it's documented.

To change the relation without `using_well_founded`, you could add a local instance that says to use `list.length` instead of `list.sizeof`:

```
def new_list_sizeof : has_sizeof (list ℕ) := ⟨list.length⟩
local attribute [instance, priority 100000] new_list_sizeof
```

The goals that this produces will be easier for you to prove than those using `sizeof`.